# mongodb "hijacking" port

Tags: networking, python

I'm having some trouble with Python HTTP Server and MongoDB. In this case HTTP server represents a REST service providing data from MongoDB.

MongoDB is running on default port (27017) at all times. When I run my HTTP server on port 7000 and terminate it afterwards with Ctrl+C

**MongoDB port**

```
netstat -tulpen | grep :27017
tcp   0  0 0.0.0.0:27017  0.0.0.0:*  LISTEN  498    8984    1276/mongod
```

**Python HTTP server port**

```
netstat -tulpen | grep :7000
tcp  0  0 0.0.0.0:7000  0.0.0.0:*  LISTEN   0    4697443    1522/python
```

Now, when I press Ctrl+C terminating this HTTP server and do a quick netstat

**MongoDB port**

```
netstat -tulpen | grep :7000 
tcp 0 0 0.0.0.0:7000     0.0.0.0:*  LISTEN  0 4697443    1550/mongod
```

If I try to connect to MongoDB using port 7000, it fails. However, MongoDB is up and running on port 27017.

I'm not even sure where to look anymore, all this is confusing.

Comment: Out of curiousity what does `lsof` say about this? `sudo lsof -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN | grep mongo`. Found it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9346431/how-can-i-see-what-ports-mongo-is-listening-on-from-mongo-shell

Comment: Thank you for commenting, these tumbleweeds were starting to feel like home. I'll post the output tomorrow, since I don't have access to the server right now.

Comment: I've been researching this Q for a bit, so just b/c there hasn't been any visible activity don't think no one is trying to help 8-)

Comment: I'm still not sure why, but it seems that Python simple web server was the culprit. I added the line `server.allow_reuse_address = True` before actually running it (before `server.serve_forever()` and it now works as expected when I terminate it with Ctrl+C. Thank you slm for responding to my silly thread.

Comment: No problem. Can you do us a favor and write up the solution? You can accept your own answer afterwards, I think this would be useful info to have here.